# Análise de Expressão Gênica utilizando datasets do Gene Expression Omnibus (R)

Tags: r

Eu sei que a proteína que procuro está nesse dataset, porém não estou conseguindo filtrar ela em meu código para fazer uma análise de expressão gênica nesse dataset em específico.

```
library(GEOquery)
gse <- getGEO("GSE8671")

if (length(gse) > 1) idx <- grep("GPL570", attr(gse, "names")) else idx <- 1
gse <- gse[[idx]]

ex <- exprs(gse)
pData(gse)
fData(gse)

summary(exprs(gse))
features <- fData(gse)
View(features)
library(dplyr)
features <- select(features, "Gene Symbol", "ID", "ENTREZ_GENE_ID")

"201482_at" %in% colnames(ex)
qsox1_index <- grep("^201482_at", colnames(exprs(gse)))
qsox1_exprs <- exprs(gse)[, qsox1_index]
```

Por enquanto estou fazendo somente para a proteína QSOX1 (ID 201482_at) mas gostaria de ampliar minha busca com outra proteína de controle para verificar sua expressão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As expressões gênicas estão no objeto `ex`. Entretanto, ele é uma matriz, e o nome de cada gene está no nome da linha dessa matriz. Dessa forma, recomendo como boa prática, transformar essa matriz em uma tibble e criar uma nova coluna chamada `ID`:

```r
library(dplyr)

ex <- ex |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(ID = rownames(ex)) |> 
  relocate(ID)
```

A função `relocate` é usada apenas para deixar a coluna `ID` no primeiro lugar do data frame. Seu uso é opcional.

Com isso feito, basta filtrar o nome `ex` pela `ID` da proteína desejada:

```r
ex |> 
  filter(ID == "201482_at")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 65
#>   ID       GSM215051 GSM215052 GSM215053 GSM215054 GSM215055 GSM215056 GSM215057
#>   <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 201482_…     1370.     1998.     1661.     1939.     1387.     1588.     1972.
#> # ℹ 57 more variables: GSM215058 <dbl>, GSM215059 <dbl>, GSM215060 <dbl>,
#> #   GSM215061 <dbl>, GSM215062 <dbl>, GSM215063 <dbl>, GSM215064 <dbl>,
#> #   GSM215065 <dbl>, GSM215066 <dbl>, GSM215067 <dbl>, GSM215068 <dbl>,
#> #   GSM215069 <dbl>, GSM215070 <dbl>, GSM215071 <dbl>, GSM215072 <dbl>,
#> #   GSM215073 <dbl>, GSM215074 <dbl>, GSM215075 <dbl>, GSM215076 <dbl>,
#> #   GSM215077 <dbl>, GSM215078 <dbl>, GSM215079 <dbl>, GSM215080 <dbl>,
#> #   GSM215081 <dbl>, GSM215082 <dbl>, GSM215083 <dbl>, GSM215084 <dbl>, …
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda! Mas nesse caso como conseguiria ver esses valores em forma de grafico?